# UIWebView scalesPageToFit does not work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using a UIPageViewController and multiple uiwebviews within it, I load all of my webviews from before with this:

```
- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < chapters.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *path;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arrayDeCapitulos objectAtIndex:i],idioma] ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *arbit;
        if (path) {
            arbit = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:arbitPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        }
        NSString *a;
        a=@"LTR";
        if ([idioma isEqualToString:@"h"]) {
            a=@"RTL";
        }
        int size=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"preferredSize"]integerValue];
        NSString *contentString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html DIR='%@'><head>"
                                 "<style>"
                                 "*{ padding-bottom:5;font-size:%i;"
                                 "    font-family:'SBL Hebrew';max-width: %fpx;}"
                                 "</style>"
                                 "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' />"
                                 "</head>"
                                 "<body>"

                                 "%@"

                                 "</BODY> </HTML>",a,size,self.view.bounds.size.width ,arbit];
        [pageStrings addObject:contentString];
    }
    pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];
}
```

Everything is normal except sometimes everything goes wrong... I've tried everything, does someone has any idea?

Then in my other class I load the uiwebview

```
[webView loadHTMLString:dataObject
                baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
webView.delegate=self;

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
    CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it hears weird, but by moving the content of the html to a div made the job.

```
NSString *contentString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html DIR='%@'><head>"
                 "<style>"
                 "*{ padding-bottom:5;font-size:%i;"
                 "    font-family:'SBL Hebrew'}"

                 "</style>"

                 "</head>"
                 "<body>"
                 "<div>%@</div>"

                 "</body> </HTML>",a,size,arbit];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *contentString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html DIR='320px'><head>"
             "<style>"
             "*{ padding-bottom:5;font-size:%i;"
             "    font-family:'SBL Hebrew'}"

             "</style>"

             "</head>"
             "<body>"
             "<div>%@</div>"

             "</body> </HTML>",size,arbit];
```

you can set div width:320px; and height 100% on the html code.